# SharePoint Web Service - GetListItems

Tags: web-services, soap, sharepoint-2013, soapui

I am trying to consume a SharePoint 2013 Web Service (`GetListItems`).

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soap:GetListItems>

         <soap:listName>OnLineFormsList</soap:listName>

         <soap:query>
            <Where>
              <Eq>
                 <FieldRef Name="Item Type" />
                 <Value Type="String">Personal</Value>
              </Eq>
             </Where>
         </soap:query>

         <viewFields>
           <FieldRef Name="Process ID" />
           <FieldRef Name="Title" />
           <FieldRef Name="Description" />
         </viewFields>

         <soap:rowLimit>50</soap:rowLimit>

         <queryOptions xmlns:SOAPSDK9=
              "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" >
           <QueryOptions/>
        </queryOptions>

         <soap:webID></soap:webID>
      </soap:GetListItems>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am trying this from SoapUI. I get the below error message:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <errorstring xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">Element &lt;Query> of parameter query is missing or invalid.</errorstring>
            <errorcode xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">0x82000000</errorcode>
         </detail>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Can anyone point out how to correctly consume this service?

List Columns:

[image: List Columns]

View: **All Items** (The default one)

I followed the instructions on this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Have you tried validating the request in soapui editor using `Alt+v` key combinations or right click and validate? Error message in response says the problem `Element <Query> of parameter query is missing or invalid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used *Sharepoint* however based on the error message and the link you provide the problem is clearly that your request doesn't validate against the schema.

I think that the problem is with the node names and the namespaces of your request nodes. Make `http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/` the default namespace for your request, and capitalize some node names (In the samples from the link you provide it use `<Query>` instead of `<query>`, `<ViewFields>` instead of `<viewField>`), you can also remove `<WebID>` since it is an optional element and in your case it's empty.

Could be more errors, but you can try with:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <GetListItems>
         <ListName>OnLineFormsList</ListName>
         <Query>
            <Where>
              <Eq>
                 <FieldRef Name="Item Type" />
                 <Value Type="String">Personal</Value>
              </Eq>
             </Where>
         </Query>

         <ViewFields>
           <FieldRef Name="Process ID" />
           <FieldRef Name="Title" />
           <FieldRef Name="Description" />
         </ViewFields>

         <RowLimit>50</RowLimit>

         <queryOptions xmlns:SOAPSDK9=
              "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" >
           <QueryOptions/>
         </queryOptions>

      </GetListItems>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! I do get a 403 FORBIDDEN error though now.

Comment: @Brian nice to help you, however as I told you I've never used *sharepoint* so I can only help you correcting your *xml* request, but I don't know what you've to check in your server to avoid the *forbbiden* surely you're missing some credentials or client certificate authentication.